# How to count rows that have the same values in two columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am doing a dataset research and I came down with a classficaition results dataset as follow.

```
   Actual Prediction
0     DS    DS
1     DS    DS
2     WS    DS
3     WD    WD
4     WS    WS
```

I want to compare both the `Actual` and `Prediction`, and only return the rows that have `Actual == DS` and `Prediction == DS`.

```
Desired Output:
    Actual Prediction
0    DS    DS
1    DS    DS
2    DS    DS
```

lines with `Actual != DS` and `Prediction == DS` are considered wrong classification

Such that I will be able to do a calculation on the accuracy of successful classification.

I have searched across quite a lot but I was not able to solve this problem by tring out a lot of dataframe built-in functions such as count, duplicate, etc.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: ``df.loc[df.eq("DS").all(1)]`` ?? I'm guessing it should return 0 and 1, there is no `DS` in Actual for row 2

Comment: Use `df[df.Actual.eq('DS') & df.Prediction.eq('DS')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'Actual': ['DS', 'WD'], 'Prediction':  ['DS', 'WD']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[(df.Actual == "DS") & (df.Prediction == "DS")]
```

Result:

```
    Actual  Prediction
0   DS      DS
```